# Padding-right: 100% works in chrome but not in IE11

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

This is the css code in the style-sheet for print it works in chrome when i try print but the same does not work for IE.I tried changing the height from auto to 400px but does not work.
The issue is it is able to show all the data in chrome but in IE it shows only for few table.Again it works perfectly fine if change the padding to 100px from 100%.

```
 @media print {
  html, body
  {
    height: auto;      
  }
  #Form
  {
     height: auto;
  }
  .Datapanel 
  {
   padding-right: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Are you tried with `display: inline-block` or `display: block` in `.Datapanel` element?

Comment: Tried it but it still works properly in chrome but not in IE

Comment: Can you make an example, for instance in a snippet here in the question, that demonstrates the issue? Also, what _is_ the issue? "does not work" is as vague as you can get.